# Displaying negative value as positive on xaml

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"></TextBlock>`

```
  private int exvalue = -1;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return exvalue; }
        set { exvalue = value;  OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));}
    }
```

I just need to convert negative to display as positive on XAML. Please note that I know I can achieve this with the converter I was wondering if there is an easier way to do it. and it's more complicated than that the value is actually binded to Datagrid column and the value is coming from dlls which I cant modify Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want this in XAML, you can use string format for that :

```
 <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat={}{0:#; #}}" />
```

[string-format-int](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-int/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.Abs()`, Abs as in Absolute value. The Math class contains a lot of handy math related methods and classes e.g. complex numbers, sin/cos/tan and so on.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.abs?view=netframework-4.7.2

e.g. in the C# code.

```
private int exvalue = -1;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return Math.Abs(exvalue); }
        set { exvalue = value;  OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));}
    }
```

Your going to have to edit the code, or you can mess around with text formatting which is an absolute pain in the neck and going to take ages, the code that you showed us isnt in the dll so I am not sure why you cannot use the value you just gave us.

If you truly cannot edit the code you showed us, in which case why post it at all, then create an intermediary class that gets the values from the collection, absolute the required values on that then bind that to the xaml.

Its pretty much a required when working with data in different formats to whats required when you cant manipulate that data directly. Consider creating a method or new property without a setter but with a getter that returns the absoluted values if you want to maintain the interface of the bound objects.

Comment: value is coming from dlls which i cant modify just edited

Comment: Use an intermediary then, convert the unmodified value to an absolute and use that instead in the xaml. Infact I would frown on making the actual value absolute instead of acting on an intermediary value as that would be changing the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use a ternary operator in the `get` if you want to avoid using any converter.

```
get { return exvalue < 0 ? exvalue * -1 : exvalue ; }
```

Comment: value is coming from dlls which i cant modify just edited

Answer (score 0):

try to set value in SET accessor of property.

```
private int exvalue = -1;

public int Value
{
    get { return exvalue; }
    set 
        { 
             if(exvalue<0)
             {
                exvalue = Math.Abs(value);
             } 
             else
             {
                exvalue=value;
             }
             OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));}
}
```